# mas-dev build won't show open file dialog on an electron app

Tags: javascript, macos, electron, electron-builder, mac-app-store

I've been trying to pack and sign my electron app using [this](https://www.techandstartup.org/tutorials/release-electron-app-on-mac-app-store) guide. I've signed the app and am able to open app, however, I'm unable to show the `open` file dialog. Here is the relevant code and configs:

package.json

```
"scripts": {
"build": "tsc",
"watch": "tsc -w",
"lint": "tslint -c tslint.json -p tsconfig.json",
"copy": "copyfiles -u 1 src/**/*.html src/**/*.css src/**/*.js dist/ && copyfiles -u 1 src/ui/assets/**/*.* dist/ && copyfiles package.json dist/",
"buildAndCopy": "npm run build && npm run copy",
"start": "npm run build && npm run copy && npm run pack && electron dist/main.js",
"test": "npm run buildAndCopy && jest --testPathPattern=tests/ --coverage",
"uitest": "npm run buildAndCopy && jest --testPathPattern=uitests/",
"pack": "npm run buildAndCopy && electron-builder --dir --config electron-builder.json -c.extraMetadata.main=dist/main.js",
"dist": "npm run buildAndCopy && electron-builder --config electron-builder.json -c.extraMetadata.main=dist/main.js",
"sign-mas": "electron-osx-sign artifacts/mas-dev/DiffLens.app --identity='Apple Development' --provisioning-profile=build/AppleDevelopment.provisionprofile",
"sign-mac": "electron-osx-sign artifacts/mac/DiffLens.app --identity='Apple Development' --provisioning-profile=build/AppleDevelopment.provisionprofile"
```

electron-builder.json

```
.
.
.
"files": [
    "dist/**/*",
    "node_modules/**/*",
    "lib/**/*",
    "package.json"
],
"mac": {
  "category": "public.app-category.developer-tools",
  "electronLanguages": ["en"],
  "target": "mas-dev",
  "type": "development",
  "hardenedRuntime": true,
  "gatekeeperAssess": false,
  "icon": "build/icon.icns",
  "entitlements": "build/entitlements.mas.plist",
  "entitlementsInherit": "build/entitlements.mas.inherit.plist",
  "provisioningProfile": "build/AppleDevelopment.provisionprofile"
}
```

build/entitlements.mas.plist

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<!DOCTYPE plist PUBLIC "-//Apple//DTD PLIST 1.0//EN" "http://www.apple.com/DTDs/PropertyList-1.0.dtd">
<plist version="1.0">
<dict>
    <key>com.apple.security.app-sandbox</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.application-groups</key>
    <array>
        <string>com.difflens.mac</string>
    </array>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write</key>
    <true/>
    <key>com.apple.security.files.user-selected.read-write</key>
    <true/>
</dict>
</plist>
```

I have a menu option in my app (`File -> Open`) which in turn calls

`let result = dialog.showOpenDialogSync(Globals.getMainWindow());`
When I try to open a file, the app just gets stuck. The open dialog box never appears (almost as if MacOS is restricting my app from accessing system files). I tried looking in `Console -> System Log` but nothing caught my eye there. AFAICT, I've specified `com.apple.security.files.downloads.read-write` in the `.plist` file, so I should be able to do open files. **What am I missing? How do I debug this?**

For reference, I build the app by running `npm run dist` first and then signing it with `npm run sign-mas`. The app works perfectly when I run it locally i.e. by just running `npm run start`. The error only occurs when I try to run the packaged version produced by electron builder. Any help is greatly appreciated!